# Passing List<int> values to AES

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some help please. I have been trying to figure out how to Decrypt an AES encrypted string using encrypt.dart.

My first problem is that I can get the Key and the IV in `List<int>` but cannot work out how to pass this to the decrypter.

The decrypter requires 32 byte length and the IV requires 16 byte lengths but when I convert either the myKey or the myIV to Hex string or String(Disaster), they land up being double the lengths. I dont know how to pass a `List<int>` to the decryptors and have tried converting them to hex string.

```
List<int> intList = [189, 249, 66, 29, 132, 72, 230, 0, 235, 175, 236, 175, 246, 114, 21, 20, 79, 4, 174, 195, 121, 156, 172, 10, 50, 64, 94, 96, 112, 85, 204, 149];
String hexString = utf8.decode(intList);
hexString = hexString.runes.map((int rune) => rune.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0').toUpperCase()).join();
```

but this again just doubles the length.

So this is where my limitation is:

```
List<int> myKey  = [84, 124, 176, 174, 139, 253, 34, 86, 205, 149, 187, 232, 133, 67, 56, 212, 180, 63, 73, 222, 33, 183, 190, 41, 62, 23, 94, 233, 133, 46, 162, 219];x11
List<int> myIV  = [183, 104, 193, 48, 247, 178, 239, 48, 249, 41, 56, 33, 255, 150, 74, 110]


final key = enc.Key.fromUtf8(*myKey*); //32 length
final iv = enc.IV.fromUtf8(*myIV*); //16 length

// Encryption
    String kelime = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    final encrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key, mode: enc.AESMode.ctr, padding: null));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(kelime, iv: iv);
    final ciphertext = encrypted.base64;
    print(ciphertext);

// Decryption
    final decrypter = enc.Encrypter(enc.AES(key, mode: enc.AESMode.ctr, padding: null));
    final decrypted = decrypter.decryptBytes(enc.Encrypted.fromBase64(ciphertext), iv: iv);
    final decryptedData = utf8.decode(decrypted);
    print(decryptedData);
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Robby

Comment: Check out the unnamed constructor for `Key` https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Key/Key.html and the analogous one for `IV` https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/IV/IV.html

Comment: You'll also need to convert your `List<int>` to typed data - check out its named constructor https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html

Comment: Humm ok let me read some more. thanks

Comment: Ok I guess what I am trying to do is convert a list<int> of :75 48 4A 23 FF 6E F3 7F 6B C9 9A 71 93 75 49 EB with size 16 bytes to a string version in 16 bytes. This makes me believe i dont understand conversions.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to a string?

Answer (score 1):

Use the unnamed `Key` constructor that takes a byte array.

```
  final key = enc.Key(Uint8List.fromList(myKey));
```

Comment: Thank you Richard, this sure helped... Now to work out how to pass Uint8List.fromList into  'final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(???, iv: iv)'

Comment: I tried final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(enc.Encrypted(Uint8List.fromList(encrypedListInt)), iv: iv); and I am now getting "Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block"

Comment: Original question shows counter mode, which won't have any padding. Update the question with an actual example. Also, `encrypt` is just a wrapper around `pointycastle` (which I find tends to obfuscate the underlying operations). Consider using `pointycastle` directly - there's even a SO tag for questions.